# Image segmentation by pixel value

Tags: image-processing, algorithm, code-request, segmentation

I'm looking for a way to segment a grayscale image (or a 2D array) by its pixel values. We look at two neighboring pixels, if their values are close within a certain threshold, then we say they are connected. How to find all the connected segments in the image?

Here are some three examples,

example 1:

```
threshold = 1;
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

give

```
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}
```

This is because 1 is connected to 2, 2 is connected to 3, etc. And all the pixels are connected. So there is only 1 component in the image.

example 2:

```
threshold = 0;
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

give

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

This is because all pixels are isolated and thus we have 9 components.

example 3:

```
threshold = 2;
data = {{5, 0, 2, 3, 10}, {9, 10, 10, 2, 2}, {10, 10, 3, 3, 3}, {8, 3, 1, 7, 
       5}, {4, 5, 0, 5, 8}};
```

give

```
{{1, 2, 2, 2, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 2, 2}, {4, 4, 2, 2, 2}, {4, 2, 2, 2, 
   2}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}}
```

This question is a spectral version of this general question: Is there a way to supply a custom function to specify the connectivity in a function like `MorphologicalComponents`? For example, something like:

```
MorphologicalComponents[data, Abs[#1 - #2] <= threshold &]
```

Comment: You could use a pair of difference filters (x and y), threshold and add the result to get the boundaries between the components, invert and use `MorphologicalComponents`. But you'll need some post-processing to fill the borders between the components

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update**: If you want 4-neighborhood, you can use `MorphologicalComponents` to do most of the work, which is fast and easy to implement (that was my original attempt, see below). But I don't think this can be adapted for 8-neighborhood. For 8-neighborhood, I would implement the [standard 2-pass connected component labeling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling#Two-pass) (this might be what `MorphologicalComponents` does internally). The idea is:

- in the first pass, scan pixels from top to bottom
- if there's a connected neighbor pixel left above, assign that label to the current pixel
- if there are more than two different labels, store the label pair for later
- if there's no connected neighbor, assign a new label

So, the pipeline looks something like this:

[image]

So the first pass assigns the labels 4 and 5 to the pixels at the right, and stores the information that 4 and 2 should be in the same component, and that 5 and 1 should be in the same component. The second pass then only requires a table lookup for each pixel.

The first pass does most of the work, and returns a "preliminary" label matrix, and a set of label pairs that should go into the same component.

Sadly, there's no efficient compilable set-data structure, so I'm using a global `Association` variable (`connectedIndices`) which means a few `MainEvaluate` calls in the compiled function:

```
isConnected = With[{t = threshold}, Compile[{x, y}, Abs[x - y] <= t]];

firstPass = With[{connectedFn = isConnected},
  Compile[{{pixels, _Real, 2}},
   Module[{x, y, componentIndex, neighborOffsets, offset, index, 
     newIndex, componentCount = 0, w, h, parent, child, relabel},
    {h, w} = Dimensions[pixels];
    componentIndex = ConstantArray[0, {h, w}];
    neighborOffsets = {{-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, -1}};
    (* scan every pixel *)
    connectedIndices = <||>;
    Do[
     (
      index = 0;
      Do[
       (* find connected neighbors above and to the left *)
       If[y + offset[[1]] >= 1 && x + offset[[2]] >= 1 &&
         y + offset[[1]] <= h && x + offset[[2]] <= w &&
         connectedFn[pixels[[y + offset[[1]], x + offset[[2]]]], 
          pixels[[y, x]]],
        newIndex = componentIndex[[y + offset[[1]], x + offset[[2]]]];
        If[index != 0 && index != newIndex,
         (* more than one label found in neighborhood: 
         newIndex and index really are the same component - 
         save information for second pass *)
         AssociateTo[connectedIndices, MinMax[{index, newIndex}] -> 1];
         ];
        index = newIndex;
        ], {offset, neighborOffsets}];
      If[index == 0,
       (* no label found in neighborhood: new component *)
       index = ++componentCount];
      componentIndex[[y, x]] = index;
      ),
     {y, 1, Length[pixels]},
     {x, 1, Length[pixels[[1]]]}
     ];
    Return[componentIndex]
    ], {{relabelConnectedComponents[__], _Integer, 1}}, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"]]
```

The second pass is straightforward: We can use graph functions to get a relabeling-lookup table from the connected label pairs:

```
Clear[relabelConnectedComponents]
relabelConnectedComponents[connectedIndices_, componentCount_] := 
 Module[{comp, relabel, count},
  comp = SortBy[
    ConnectedComponents[
     Graph[Range[componentCount], 
      UndirectedEdge @@@ connectedIndices]], Min];
  relabel = ConstantArray[0, componentCount];
  Do[
   Do[relabel[[oldIndex]] = index, {oldIndex, comp[[index]]}],
   {index, Length[comp]}];
  relabel]
```

(note that this graph only contains one node per *component* not per *pixel*, so this is much much faster than using `ConnectedComponents` on the pixels directly)

And apply that lookup table:

```
Clear[secondPass]
secondPass[componentIndex_] := Module[{relabel},
   (* second pass - relabel connected components *)
   If[Length[Keys@connectedIndices] == 0, componentIndex,
    relabel = 
     relabelConnectedComponents[Keys[connectedIndices], 
      Max[componentIndex]];
    relabel[[#]] & /@ componentIndex
    ]];
```

Usage: `secondPass@firstPass[data]`

This seems to be about 5-6 times slower than the built-in `MorphologicalComponents`, which means it's about 50% slower than the method below, which works on upsample data. But it should work for any neighborhood.

---

*(Original answer, using `MorphologicalComponents`)*

First, two small utility functions: `upsample` duplicates every value in a list, `showGrid` displays a matrix of numbers:

```
upsample = Riffle[#, #] &;    

showGrid[d_, opt___] := 
 Grid[d /. n_?NumberQ :> Item[n, Background -> ColorData[95][n]], opt,
   ItemSize -> {1.5, 2}, 
  Dividers -> {{{{True, False}}, -1 -> True}, {{{True, False}}, -1 -> 
      True}}]
```

You could upsample the data (duplicate every row and column):

```
dataUpsampled = upsample /@ upsample[data];
showGrid[dataUpsampled]
```

[image]

Then you take the differences between rows, columns and across corners, and compare the differences to the threshold:

```
padAndThreshold = 
  PadRight[UnitStep[Abs[#] - threshold - 1], 
    Dimensions[dataUpsampled]] &;
dx = padAndThreshold[Differences /@ dataUpsampled];
dy = padAndThreshold[Differences@dataUpsampled];
dxy = padAndThreshold[
   dataUpsampled[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]] - dataUpsampled[[;; -2, ;; -2]]];
dyx = padAndThreshold[
   dataUpsampled[[2 ;;, ;; -2]] - dataUpsampled[[;; -2, 2 ;;]]];
```

and combine them:

```
boundaries = UnitStep[-(dx + dy + dxy + dyx)];
showGrid[boundaries]
```

[image]

now you can use `MorphologicalComponents` on this array:

```
showGrid[MorphologicalComponents[boundaries]]
```

[image]

To get the original sized result, simply remove the even rows and columns:

```
comp = MorphologicalComponents[boundaries][[;; ;; 2, ;; ;; 2]];
showGrid[comp, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I always don't konw why the most right-bottom number is `2`..

Comment: @yode: Because he's using 8-neighborhood and you're using 4-neighborhood.

Comment: Thanks,changed.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same without duplicating the image size (with `Image` as input)?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: Good question. All answers so far multiply the data (think of the original pixels as nodes and the three "extra" pixels as nodes connecting them). You could write your own flood-fill or component labeling algorithm of course, but I'm not sure if that's going to be faster than using an inbuilt function on larger data.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: Alternatively, you could try to access the IPP libraries that ship with Mathematica, which contains a function `FloodFill_Grad` that does exactly what this question asks for

Comment: I don't sure ``GeneralUtilities`ColorArrayForm`` can help you a little..

Comment: @nikie Thanks! Is there an internal API to access IPP from Mathematica, and where is the IPP located in Mathematica installation? And by the way, do you know what are the image processing functions based on, are they implemented based on IPP, opencv, or others?

Comment: It seems that the result is not correct for `threshold=2;data={{1, 5, 11, 1, 1}, {3, 16, 18, 7, 16}, {4, 18, 15, 2, 8}, {5, 0, 4, 
  18, 5}, {20, 19, 20, 12, 14}}`. Grid data[[2,4]] should be connected to data[[3,5]].

Comment: Also, it seems that your solution is at least two orders of magnitude faster than any of the other two! I'm wondering how `MorphologicalComponents` achieves such incredible performance.

Comment: @xslittlegrass: Damn, you're right, the result isn't correct. And I'm not sure I can fix it, at least not for 8-neighborhood. I don't see how I can connect $2/4$ and $3/5$ without connecting $2/5$ and $3/4$ at the same time. I'll have to think about that...

Comment: Regarding speed: I guess `MorphologicalComponents` just needs two passes over packed data, and it's probably written in C as it's meant for large images. Graph algorithms have to work with much more complex data structures.

Comment: Regarding IPP: Sorry, no idea how you can access it. On a Windows system, the dll `ippcv.dll` is in `SystemFiles\Kernel\Binaries\Windows`, but it's a complicated call (you have to pass data structures and preallocated memory to the function). Should be possible with `LibraryLink`, but it would probably take a few hours (or days...) to get it to work...

Comment: Sorry for cut in.Actually `ImageFilter` and `ArrayFilter` strike to my mind when I first time to glance the question.Maybe they can help to improve the efficiency.

Comment: "Sadly, there's no efficient compilable set-data structure" - `Part` allows in-place modification of an array and is [compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/280).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: Yes, but I don't want to write my own dynamic list + red/black-tree data structure for this.

Answer (score 10):

Almost,for your example three:

```
threshold = 2;
coor = Catenate[Array[{##} &, Dimensions[data]]];
rule = Dispatch[Thread[coor -> Flatten[data]]];
Rotate[g = EdgeDelete[NearestNeighborGraph[coor,DistanceFunction -> 
     ChessboardDistance], _?(Abs[Subtract @@ (# /. rule)] > threshold &)], -Pi/2]
```

[image]

```
MatrixForm[SparseArray[Catenate[Tuples /@ MapIndexed[Rule, ConnectedComponents[g]]]]]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! But it seems that your solution scales poorly with the size of data. For instance, `data = RandomInteger[20, {100, 100}];` takes about 60 seconds for your solution, while it takes about 4 seconds for my dfs solution, and takes about 0.01 second for @nikie's solution.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution based on yode's code, but it uses depth-first search which runs in linear time with the size of data.

```
N0 = First@Dimensions[data];
coor = Catenate[
   CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{{1, 1}, Dimensions[data]}]];
g = NearestNeighborGraph[coor, DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance];
vls = VertexList[g];
els = {};

isConnected = (If[
     Abs[data[[Sequence @@ #[[1]]]] - data[[Sequence @@ #[[2]]]]] <= 
      threshold, AppendTo[els, UndirectedEdge[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]]; 
    Pause[0.1]; &);

Dynamic[connect = 
     Graph[vls, els, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
      VertexCoordinates -> (coor /. {i_, j_} -> {j, N0 - i})]]    

DepthFirstScan[g, {"FrontierEdge" -> isConnected, 
  "BackEdge" -> isConnected, "ForwardEdge" -> isConnected, 
  "CrossEdge" -> isConnected}]
```

This shows the action of the process

[image]

Comment: Doesn't `ConnectedComponents` have O(n) running time, too? (`MorphologicalComponents` probably too) If I had to guess, I'd say Mathematica's ConnectedComponents is probably implemented using depth-first search, too.

Comment: @nikie You are right. I just saw that yode edited his answer. He was using `RelationGraph` before, which runs at O(n^2). Thanks for your answer by the way.